# Trying to implement a PHP crawler?

Tags: php, dom, web-crawler

I am trying ti implement the PHP crawler in my website. My main motive is to get the price of the product from other websites. For that i am trying to use dom parser but my script is not working. my code for parsing a div whose class is prc is:-

```
<?php
include('simplehtmldom/simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://www.ebay.in');
$html->find('div', 1)->class = 'prc';   
        echo $html;      
?>
```

Comment: eBay already has their API located [here](http://go.developer.ebay.com/developers/ebay/products/).

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm)? It looks like you are `echo`ing an object (the `$html` variable), which is not how you would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps (it doesn't require SimpleHTMLDom by the way):

```
$className = 'prc'; // Name of the class

$domDocument = new DOMDocument('1.0');
@$domDocument->loadHTMLFile('http://www.ebay.in');
$domXPath = new DOMXPath($domDocument);

// Obtain all elements with the specified class name
$prcs = $domXPath->query(
    "//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $className ')]"
);

for ($i = 0; $i < $prcs->length; $i++) {
    // For each item found, store it in $result
    $result[] = $prcs->item($i)->firstChild->nodeValue;
}

// Display results
print_r($result);
```